# Need help in remove a specific element from Array using the index

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I actually need help in remove `myStudents[1]` element from `myStudents` array in the `GradeBookTest1` class by invoking the `gbook.remove(1)` method, which takes index `1` as an argument and passes it on to the `remove(int inputIndex)` parameter variable in the `GradeBook1` class.

You can see my remove method in the GradeBook1 class and stuck there.

**Note:** Due to clarity, I have removed rest of the stuff from the `GradeBook1` class except the `remove(int inputIndex)` method. Thanks!

```
public class GradeBookTest1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Create an array of students
    Student[] myStudents = new Student[4];
    myStudents[0] = new Student("John", 72.5, new Date(1995, 12, 21));
    myStudents[1] = new Student("Jane", 85, new Date(1996, 1, 12));
    myStudents[2] = new Student("Bob", 64.3, new Date(1994, 5, 18));
    myStudents[3] = new Student("Bill", 98, new Date(1998, 1, 1));

    // Use the above array to initialize an object of GradeBook
    GradeBook1 gbook = new GradeBook1(myStudents);
    // print the grade book
    System.out.println("My GradeBook:");
    System.out.println(gbook);

    /* Let's remove a student from grade book */
    gbook.remove(1); // remove the second student

    // print the grade book again!
    System.out.println("My GradeBook:");
    System.out.println(gbook);

    }
}

public class GradeBook1 { 

    public void remove(int inputIndex) 
    {
        Student[] stud = new Student[students.length];

        for (int i=0; i<students.length; i++ )
        {
            stud[i] = new Student(students[i].getName(), students[i].getGrade(), students[i].getBirthdate());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why not you are using `ArrayList` ?

Comment: If you have to use array (instead of `ArrayList`), why do you create array which is same length as the original one, even though you know it will need to have one element less? Anyway, for hint, use two indexes, one for destination and another for source array, in your copying loop. Then figure out how you can actually not copy the `inputIndex` element...

Comment: Actually, I am bound to use Array only.

Comment: Also, generally speaking, if someone does your homework here for you, you'll learn less. You should at least make an attempt, write code that at least *tries* to remove the indicated index. Now you just have code for copying the entire array (and then losing the result), and we don't know if you wrote even that yourself....

Comment: @hyde, I understand, but let me tell you that this is just a lab practice and I spent like 3-4 hours on it and also I wrote that `remove(int inputIndex)` code myself. Hope you understand.

Comment: I assume you are using some proper Java IDE. Have you tried running your code with its debugger? Look at `stud` and `students` arrays as you step through the code, then note the point where `stud` array goes wrong (ie. the point you copy removed element to it). Then try to make a version which just leaves that element to `null`. Then improve it so that it actually skips the element entirely, producing `stud` which is 1 shorter that `student`. Secret to programming is making small enough changes, one at a time.

Comment: Inside `remove()` what is `students` you used as `students.length`?

Comment: @rakeb.mazharul, `students` is an array and `students.length` is its length.

Comment: You're not at all doing what you're supposed to do in the `remove()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way is using ArrayList but another simple way can be:

```
public int[] removeElement(int[] original, int element){
    int[] n = new int[original.length - 1];
    System.arraycopy(original, 0, n, 0, element ); // can be replaced by a loop
    System.arraycopy(original, element+1, n, element, original.length - element-1);
    return n;
}
```

[System.arraycopy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)) in the above code snippet can be replaced by the following for loops. You can modify the code as per your requirement as it is simple.

```
for (int i = 0; i < element; i++) {
    n[i] = original[i];
}
for (int i = element + 1; i < original.length; i++) {
    n[i - 1] = original[i];
}
```

If you want to copy all elements from one array to another, you can simple use `System.arraycopy( src, 0, dest, 0, src.length )` where `src` and `dest` are two integer arrays.

Comment: Too bad, that I think OP is also not supposed to use `arraycopy` either, but instead they're supposed to be learning something more basic from the exercise ;)

Comment: I agree but i array copy can be accomplished by iterating through a loop and since OP has used loop, i believe OP can convert the above mentioned code to an iterative version :)

Comment: @hyde is right. Actually Wasi Ahmad, this `System.arraycopy` is above my knowledge. Do you have a simpler way dealing with loops only? Thanks

Comment: @TitanicLover i have given the loop code. Its just iterating through a loop skipping the element that you want to remove!

Comment: Thanks, but `gbook.remove(1);` has been used, which means input parameter of `remove()` method should be index accepting only.

Answer (score 2):

Take the following program as example :

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(remove(a, 5)));

}

static int[] remove(int[] array, int index) {
    if (!rangeCheck(array, index)) return null;

    int[] _new = new int[array.length - 1];
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        _new[i] = array[i];
    }

    for (i = index + 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        _new[i - 1] = array[i];
    }
    return _new;
}

static boolean rangeCheck(int[] a, int index) {
    return index >= 0 && index < a.length;
}
}
```

Here is the catch :: above program is `0` index based. If you need to remove the `n'th` element your index should be `n-1`.